# Read console/errors of iPhone app without new build via Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, build, console

I developed an app and already tested it in Xcode and on my physical iPhone device.

After a lot of testing on my iPhone the app quits after starting. 
I guess this is because of an empty array, but I am not sure.

Is there a possibility to read the console of my already built app on my iPhone? Because when I am testing the app on Xcode everything works fine - I guess the error occurs in only very specific cases...

I don't want to build the app again on my physical device, because I am pretty sure everything works fine then and I won't be able to recreate the exact situation. 
So I would like to connect the phone to my macbook and run the app on my phone in Xcode without rebuilding it first.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a free provisioning?

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding your question correct, but if you ask if I have a developer account, no I haven't yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect your phone to your system and open Xcode.
2. The Window menu in Xcode Select Device and Simulators from the
   Window menu.
3. Select your device from the left panel.
4. The toggle logs button Make sure that the logs are expanded. If they
   are not, press the small up arrow in the bottom left corner of the
   main pane.
5. Click the Save Console button (at the bottom right) to save the log
   information within the console.

Comment: Thanks!
Quite hard to track down the error because it constantly writes down all sorts of things into the console but I guess it is because of what Kerberos wrote.

I will pit your answer as the "correct" one because that's what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a free Apple Developer account it is normal, it has not crashed.. it simply refuse to run.

Apple has imposed 'new' limitations on the 'free' provisioning profiles, whit this limitations you can run the app on a physical device for 7 days, then you must recreate a new profile with a new deploy on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Even without **XCode** you can get the logs by using [**iOS Console**](https://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/) which is free and works exactly as **XCode**'s console.

As for starting the app again without rebuilding from **XCode**, you can use `⌃⌘R` to speed up your tests.